# Complexity analysis of loop with limited looping time

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

I'm wondering whether the big-o complexity of the following code should be o(1) or o(n).

```
for(int i=0;i<n && n<100;i++){sum++;}
```

Here's what i think:
since n is limited to be lower than 100, worst case will be O(99) + O(98) + ... + O(1) = 99 * O(1) = O(1)
However, by intuition, the code is somehow O(n) due to the loop.

Would really appreciate it if someone can advise me on this.
Thank you!

Comment: Complexity analysis is for algorithms. It doesn't make sense for just a loop without further information. What is the loop looping over?

Comment: The loop is looping over operation with o(1) complexity. Eg. Sum++;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively it is O(1) because as n increases the runtime does not increase after a certain point. However, this is an edge case, as were n bounded by a much higher number, say the maximum value of an int, it would seem to be no different than if n was not bounded at all. However, when considering runtime using complexity theory we usually ignore things like that maximum size of an int.

Another way to think of this is that the number of iterations grows linearly with n for n in (0,100) and is constant otherwise. When considering n can be any value, however, the algorithm is definitely O(1)

This is all assuming each iteration of the loop takes constant time.

For more information look up Liouville's theorem.

Comment: *algorithm is O(n) for n in (0,100)* that does not make sense. The Big O notation is defined and applies only asymptotically when n->infinity. It is not defined over any other interval.

Comment: @A.S.H I said it was another way to think of it, and then clarified that because n can be any value the algortithm is really O(1). I was attempting to illustrate why the algorithm is O(1), and admit I may have done so badly. Do you have any suggestions for how I can edit it to be clearer?

Comment: You can eventually say something like *"the **number of iterations** grows linearly with n in the interval [0, 100]"*, without any reference to big-O ;)

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you, that wording is much better, I edited it in.